# negative value stored in unsigned int

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

we know if we want to store `num=-1` in 32 bit signed int its bits representation will look like
`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

but if I do like this `num=-1`
`unsigned int num1 = num` then num1 bit representation will look like `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

we also know that in unsigned int msb does not represent sign ,it contributes to magnitude ,I want to know why there are all ones in num1 representation how can I predict the value for -2 in unsigned int

Note I was trying all the operation in cpp language

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned int num = -1;
    ///i want to know what will be the bit representation of num=-2
    while(num){
        cout<<(num&1);
        num>>=1;
    }

}
```

Comment: regarding your first sentence, perhaps you should try inspecting the representation on your system

Comment: They're both stored as all 1's.  Google "Two's complement"

Comment: but suppose in 8 bit we represent   1 as 0000 0001 and to get -1
first we will do 1s complement 1111 1110 and then two complement like this 1111 1111

Comment: No, that's not how signed integers work on almost all modern systems. -1 is all ones.

Comment: Recommended readings: [Why you shouldn't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/9254539) and [Why `using namespace std` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9254539).

Comment: Standard unsigned types in C++ use modulo (aka "wrap around") arithmetic.  So storing `-1` to an `unsigned` type gives the largest *numerical* value that type can represent.   For a 32-bit unsigned type, that is `4294967295`.  Which will have an "all bits set" representation.   A value of `-2` will be stored as `4294967294`, which will have all bits except the last set.    Bear in mind that an `unsigned` is not guaranteed to be 32 bit (it can be 16 bit, since the maximum value it can represent is guaranteed to be at least `65535`).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the MSB of unsigned ints contributes to magnitude, as do all the other bits. You can see since `unsigned int num1 = -1` gives `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` which is the greatest possible unsigned value (2^32). -2 is literally `num1 - 1`. Therefore you can just subtract 1 and get `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110` (2^32 - 1).

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/two-s-complement

Answer (score 0):

When you assigned  a negative number to unsigned int the negative  number as you said the first bit is sign bit and the other is binary of the number for example binary representation -2 is 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 unsigned int get two's complete of this number .If you want to convert the signed binary to two's complete  from first 1 from right every bit get not except for signed bit so two's  complete  of -2 should be 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110.